# FFMPEG wasm - Failed to parse URL

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

I am getting this: `RuntimeError: abort(TypeError: Failed to parse URL from /Users/name/git/ffmpegtestproject/node_modules/@ffmpeg/core/dist/ffmpeg-core.wasm`.

My package.json looks like this:

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@ffmpeg/core": "^0.11.0",
    "@ffmpeg/ffmpeg": "^0.11.6",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1"
  },
```

My node-file looks like this:

```js
const express = require("express");
const path = require('path')
const { dirname } = path;
const multer = require("multer");
const { createFFmpeg } = require("@ffmpeg/ffmpeg");
const app = express();


const upload = multer({ storage: multer.memoryStorage() })
const ffmpegInstance = createFFmpeg({ log: true })
let ffmpegLoading = ffmpegInstance.load()

async function getFfmpeg() {
  if (ffmpegLoading) {
    await ffmpegLoading;
    ffmpegLoading = undefined
  }
  return ffmpegInstance
}
```

Crashes immediately when running `node index.js`, with the error provided above.

I can see the wasm-binary in that directory, so not sure what the issue could be. This is in Nodejs, running version v18.12.0

Answer (score 0):

I have confirmed that downgrading the Lambda from Node.js 18.x to Node.js 16.x solved the problem for us.

I do not know why ffmpeg is throwing that error because all we can see is that general message "Failed to parse URL". But until we get better clarity on that you could break out the functions that need to use ffmpeg into their own Lambda or even their own Application, and run only that portion on Node.js 16.x as a workaround.

Comment: Unfortunately now AWS is telling me that I have to get all my Lambdas upgraded from node 16 by June 12, 2024. So I’m going to have to dig into this and figure out the real fix. Who knows, maybe it will just magically work with the very latest node builds available. I will report my findings here.

Comment: Update... I tried upgrading to npm packages @ffmpeg/core@0.12.6 and @ffmpeg/ffmpeg@0.12.10 to see if these would resolve the problem, but @ffmpeg/core@0.12.X is too large to deploy to Lambda. Also there are breaking code changes going from 0.11 to 0.12, which the docs seem to do a good job of explaining.

But I am going to explore the path of installing ffmpeg from johnvansickle.com as described in this Medium post: https://virkud-sarvesh.medium.com/building-ffmpeg-layer-for-a-lambda-function-a206f36d3edc

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by these steps:

- Upgraded my Lambdas to use nodejs20.x which runs Amazon Linux 2023 as the host OS
- Created an EC2 instance of Amazon Linux 2023, size t2.large
- Used this amazing build script for ffmpeg to make an executable for Amazon Linux x686: https://github.com/markus-perl/ffmpeg-build-script
- Note that markus-perl's script pulls source code from https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/ which is awesome
- I chose to use the version of markus-perl's script that is without GPL and non-free codes, but you must make your own decision. There are two slightly different commands so follow the one that you want.
- After the build completed (it took a few hours and had to be restarted a few times, but it nicely picks up where it left off after a hang), I used FileZilla to connect to my AL2023 instance and transfer app/workspace/bin/ffmpeg to my local build machine. Then I used serverless to create a Lambda Layer for ffmpeg.
- Once the Layer was created, I changed my code so that it uses node's child_process and fs to run commands against ffmpeg. Basically I use spawnSync and fs to put my source .webm file into the /tmp directory, and then call spawnSync with arguments and ask ffmpeg to convert it to .mp4. Then I read the output .mp4 file and use Buffer to convert it to Base64, and I'm done.

Here is my function that accepts a DataUri .webm file and returns a DataUri .mp4 file:

```
module.exports.webmToMp4 = async (strWebmDataUri) => {
    var strFilename = mojo.crypto.getMD5(strWebmDataUri);
    var strFilenameWebm = strFilename + ".webm";
    var strFilenameMp4 = strFilename + ".mp4";

    const { spawnSync } = require("child_process");
    const { readFileSync, writeFileSync, unlinkSync } = require("fs");

    // strip intro bytes to obtain pure base64 string
    const strBase64 = strWebmDataUri.split(",")[1];

    // use fs Buffer to convert the base64 to a buffer
    const bufWebm = Buffer.from(strBase64, "base64");

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // use ffmpeg layer to do the work!
    // write file to disk
    writeFileSync("/tmp/" + strFilenameWebm, bufWebm);

    let fs = require("fs");

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Use this if you want to log contents of tmp and opt directories
    /*
    var files = [];
    files = fs.readdirSync("/tmp");
    console.log("/tmp=" + files);
    files = fs.readdirSync("/opt");
    console.log("/opt=" + files);
    */
    //
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    var ls = spawnSync(
        "/opt/ffmpeg",
        [
            "-i",
            "/tmp/" + strFilenameWebm,
            "-c:v",
            "copy",
            "/tmp/" + strFilenameMp4
        ],
        { encoding: "utf8" },
        { stdio: "pipe" }
    );
    console.log('ls: ', ls);

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Use this if you want to log version info about currently installed ffmped
    /*
    ls = spawnSync(
        "/opt/ffmpeg",
        [
            "-report",
            "-f",
            "v4l2",
            "-list_formats",
            "all",
            "-i",
            "/dev/video0",
            "2>",
            "/tmp/formats.txt"
        ],
        { encoding: "utf8" },
        { stdio: "pipe" }
    );
    console.log('ls: ', ls);
    */
    //
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // read file from disk
    const mp4File = readFileSync("/tmp/" + strFilenameMp4);

    // delete the temp files
    unlinkSync("/tmp/" + strFilenameWebm);
    unlinkSync("/tmp/" + strFilenameMp4);
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // convert the Uint8Array to base64 and append the intro bytes
    const strMp4DataUri = "data:video/mp4;codecs=h264;base64," + Buffer.from(mp4File).toString("base64");

    // return the (awesome) mp4 DataUri
    return strMp4DataUri;

}
```